# C++ Class Output

Tags: c++, class, object, output

i would love to understand how this one works!

if i have this code for example

```
class myclass

{
    public :

        int a;

        myclass(){a=0; cout<<"first"<<endl;}

        myclass(int i){a=i;cout<<"second"<<endl;}

        ~myclass(){cout<<a<<endl;}

};

class yourclass:protected myclass

{
    int x;
    myclass m1;

    public:

        myclass m2;

        yourclass (int i): m2(3),myclass(i){x=i; a=7;}

}
```

and i'll make an object like this

```
yourclass ob1(5);
```

can you please explain how to works? how to calls constructors ?

Thank you

Comment: It seems like the output would be showing you the order that the constructors are called.  Where is the confusion?

Comment: No, My question how it is work?

Comment: Do you want to understand why it gets the output it does?

Comment: @VaughnCato: "can you please explain how to works? how to calls constructors ?" ==> "Can you please explain the resulting output? I don't quite get why I get the output I observe" or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare an object of a class `myclass` like this:

```
myclass ob1(5);
```

it means that you've created it with the **second** constructor which accepts `int` parameter. In other words, you literally called the **second** constructor. By the way the object is created on stack.

When you declare an object of a class `myclass` like this:

```
myclass ob1;
```

it means that you've created it with the **first** constructor which is parameterless. The right term for parameterless constructor is **default** constructor. In other words, you literally called the **default** (the **first** one) constructor. By the way the object is created on stack too (as in the previous case).

When objects are created on stack they are destructed automatically when the object **goes out of scope**. The notion of **scope** applies to the **blocks** of code which include functions/methods/blocks. You can easily distinguish the block by a pair of curly brackets `{}`. For example:

```
void function() {
  myclass ob1;
} // <--- think of ob1 being destructed at this point
```

the object `ob1` will go out of scope when function finishes execution and accordingly the destructor for `ob1` is **automatically called**. Another example:

```
void function() {
  while(true) {
    myclass ob1;
  } // <--- think of ob1 being destructed at this point

  // ob1 does not exist here!
}
```

notice the infinite loop and the object `ob1` created inside it on every iteration. You can clearly see that curly brackets define a block which can combine multiple statements that constitute each iteration (currently there is only 1 statement). Accordingly, the object `ob1` will be automatically destructed in the end of each iteration.

The notion of scope applies to class members too. For instance, say you have a class `wrapper`, and you declare `myclass` as its member (`m1`) in the following way:

```
class wrapper {
  public:
  myclass m1;
};
```

Then lets take one of the previous examples and create an object of `wrapper` on stack:

```
void function() {
  wrapper w;
} // <--- destructor of w called first, destructor of w.m1 is called after
```

First the execution of the default constructor of `w` is started, during which `w.m1` is created  (with default constructor in this case because I didn't specify in the constructor of `w` which constructor of `w.m1` I'd like to call). Then the constructor of `w` finishes the execution, and `w` can be deemed as officially created. The execution of `function` continues.

When `function` finishes execution, `w` goes out of scope, and as you remember its destructor is called automatically then. As soon as the destructor of `w` finishes the execution, the destructor of `w.m1` is automatically called too. You can think of it as the object `w` has its own internal scope while it's alive, and a soon as it dies, all of its members go out of scope and should die too.

Comment: <code>yourclass (int i): m2(3),myclass(i){x=i; a=7;}</code>
this line confusing me! 
it calls myclass(i) first.. then goes back to m1 !!?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's take it easy and analyze it step by step.

**First class**

```
class myclass {
public :
    int a;
    myclass(){a=0; cout<<"first"<<endl;}
    myclass(int i){a=i;cout<<"second"<<endl;}
    ~myclass(){cout<<a<<endl;}
};
```

Here we are defining a class `myclass` which have a single member variable `a` of type `int`. It declares a default constructor (with no arguments) which assigns to `a`, `0` and then proceed to print `first`.

We also have a one-parameter constructor that initialize `a` to that first parameter, and prints `second`, and a destructor which simply prints the value of the member variable a before deallocating it.

**Initialization list**

Now, within constructors you can define an *initialization list* which is on the form

```
<class name>(...) a(x), b(y), c(z), ... {}
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This *initialization list* is necessary when there's no default constructor available for the type of any member variable of the class. Suppose we create a `nogood` class without a default constructor and define our main class to have a member of type `nogood`, how would he initialize that member variable? You can expect it to wait until the constructor body is executed.

**Second class**

```
class yourclass : protected myclass {
    int x; 
    myclass m1;
public:
    myclass m2;
    yourclass (int i): m2(3),myclass(i){x=i; a=7;}
};
```

Now yourclass inherits `protected` from `myclass`. What does it means? It means that whatever in `myclass` is public or protected, will be protected in `yourclass` (whatever is private will still be private).

The class `yourclass` defines two private members `x` and `m1` and one public member `m2`. It doesn't define any default constructor for it and defines a single parameter constructor instead (that can actually be also used to implicitly convert an `int` to `yourclass` if required).

**Output: constructors**

Firstly it calls the protected sub object's constructor producing `second`.
Then, since we haven't initialize `m1` explicitly, it will initialize it with the default constructor producing the output `first`.
Finally in the constructor we initialize `m2(3)` which is of type `myclass` which will call `myclass::myclass(int)` producing `second` as output. So the output is:

```
second
first
second
```

**Output: destructors**

Now for the destructors calls, it will call the destructors for each member variables in the reverse order to their initialization. The order of initialization was: `m1`, `m2`. The reverse order is `m2`, `m1`. `m2` was initialized with `3` in the initialize list, `m1` was initialized to `0` by default. Then finally it calls the `ob1` destructor which was initialized to `7`. Therefore the final output is:

```
second
first
second
3
0
7
```

Comment: But the output is

Second \n first \n second \n 3 \n 0 'n 7

Comment: @Z3TA, yeah i was mistaken. edited.